# how check exist value in same column?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

i have data grid view `Datagrideview1`
how i check in Cell End Edit event 
to increase quantity (1) by '1' each time i repeat same number 3232

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
                {
                    string itemInfo;
                    itemInfo = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                    var matchedRow = dataGridView1.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>()
                                     .FirstOrDefault(row => row.Cells[0].Value != null &&
                                                          row.Cells[0].Value.Equals(itemInfo[0]));
                    if (matchedRow != null)
                    {
                        int qty = (int)matchedRow.Cells[3].Value + 1;
                        double price = (double)matchedRow.Cells[4].Value;
                        matchedRow.Cells[7].Value = price * qty;
                    }
                }
            }
```

[image]

Comment: what problem you are facing?

Comment: i wanna each time i type same number (3232) only increase quantity ( without add new rows )

Comment: @KOKO I made your image to be the part of the question instead of just a link.

Comment: ok i searching for ur help :)